# return lines in a row containing a string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i have a file like this:

```
device1;interface Gi0/1
device1;interface Gi0/2
device1;interface Gi0/3
device1; description Hello
device1;interface Gi0/4
device2;interface Gi0/1
device2; ip vrf forwarding xxx-vrf
device2;interface Gi0/2
device2;interface Gi0/3
device2;interface Gi0/4
device2; ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.254
```

I want this to return each interface that does not have some other config that does not begin with 'interface' on the next line (see above) -- ie. in this case, i'd want:

```
device1;interface Gi0/1
device1;interface Gi0/2
device1;interface Gi0/4
device1;interface Gi0/2
device2;interface Gi0/3
```

I am finding this tricky to get my head around, not entirely sure how to go about it. Apologies for my amateurishness.

s.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '/interface/{if(p)print p; p=$0; next}{p=x} END{if(p)print p}' file
```

### ---

Here is an explanation:

```
awk '
  /interface/ {      # if a line contains "interface"
    if(p"")print p   # then if variable p is non-empty (and if the previous line contained
                     # "interface"), then print its content.
    p=$0             # store the current line in variable "p" (if it contains "interface)
    next             # read the next line
  }
  {                  # if the line does not contain "interface"
    p=x              # empty variable p by assigning an empty variable to it
  }
  END {              # After all lines have been processed
    if(p"")print p   # then if variable p still contains something, print it.
  }
' file
```

EDIT: added double quotes to p in if condition to force it into string context.

Comment: thanks! beautiful. i really should learn awk, but it doesn't seem so user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk 'a=/interface/{if(b)print b;b=$0}!a{b=""}END{print b}' file
```

Produces

```
device1;interface Gi0/1
device1;interface Gi0/2
device1;interface Gi0/4
device2;interface Gi0/2
device2;interface Gi0/3
```

Comment: Hi Jidder, it needs an END section, otherwise if there is a lonely interface on the last line, it will not get printed..